# Error with typing certain problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need assistance in starting/solving this problem.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I know $x$ is a subset of $A$ or $B$ by the definition of a powerset.

So would this apply for this problem?

Comment: I think you meant to say $P(A) + P(B) = P(A \cup B)$. Keeping in mind that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ you'll probably get to the correct answer. Also, keep in mind that you should provide some context for your posts and, more importantly, you should share you own attempts on solving the problem.

Comment: $P(A)$ denotes the set of all the subsets of $A$ ? Or a probability ?...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe its the power set of A.

Comment: @PierreCarre may I ask you a personal question ? Is PierreCarre your real name, or just a pun on the formula for the area of a disc ?...

Comment: @PierreCarre no this is not probability. Its dealing with sets/power sets/ subsets.

Comment: @k.rudin this is what i meant about context!

Comment: @PierreCarre I thought it was clear by saying sufficient and necessary conditions. Sorry.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, Not my real name! You got it right! In fact I even tried to change my login name to my real name but it seems that I have to wait for 20 days or so.

Comment: @PierreCarre Hahaha thanks :) I asked because I know someone whose name is really Pierre Carré ;)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose first that $A \not\subset B$ and $B \not\subset A$. Then there exists $a \in A \setminus B$ and $b \in B\setminus A$. The subset $\lbrace a,b \rbrace$ of $A \cup B$ is not a subset of $A$, nor a subset of $B$. So you don't have equality.

Suppose now that $A \subset B$. Then $A \cup B = B$, so of course $P(B) \subset P(A) \cup P(B)$. Moreover, all subsets of $A$ are subset of $B$, so you get $P(A) \cup P(B) = P(A\cup B)$. It is the same if $B \subset A$.

So the condition is that $A \subset B$ or $B \subset A$.